# AppleScript: multiple buttons in "choose from list"

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I have a script which makes users choose from different options in a list. I want there to be three buttons; OK, Cancel and Help (display a dialog with guidance).

However, it seems that I cannot use the "buttons" parameter within a list.

**So how do I add additional buttons?** (with a custom name, that displays a dialogue)

Current script:

```
set MyList to {"A", "B", "C"}

set Chosen to 
    (choose from list MyList with title "Connect to" 
    with prompt "What do you want to connect to?" 
    OK button name "Connect" cancel button name "Abort" ---and help
    with multiple selections allowed) as text
```

Comment: `choose from list` supports only two buttons.

Comment: And there is no workaround for adding a third choice?

Comment: Not with pure AppleScript unless you use a (second) standard dialog which opens the list dialog. An alternative is an AppleScriptObjC app with a custom dialog.

Comment: Done. I will delete the related comments later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `choose from list` only supports two buttons, you can use AppleScriptObjC to create very rich alerts/dialogs. I recommend starting with Shane Stanley's ***free*** [Myriad Tables Lib](https://latenightsw.com/support/freeware/). Here's an example:

[image]

To learn more, read **Chapter 26:Richer Interfaces** of Shane's excellent $15 book ***Everyday AppleScriptObjC***, available [here](https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/everyday_book.html). You could also look at Dialog Toolkit on the same page. Because Cocoa alerts and dialogs provide an "accessory view", you can put many additional controls in there.

Comment: Updated the link to the current location of Myriad Tables. Note that this product is no longer being  maintained, but it is still usable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `choose from list` supports only two buttons.

Alternatives are a (second) standard dialog which opens the list dialog or an AppleScriptObjC app with a custom dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 vanilla examples of inserting a "menubar" which provides additional choices in the standard "choose from list" menu...

[1] This activates a secondary menu from the top menu item.

```
return my choosefromList(lst)
property lst : ("
1
2
3
")
property prev : {}
on choosefromList(lst)
    repeat
        repeat
            repeat while lst begins with linefeed or lst begins with return
                set lst to text 2 thru -1 of lst
            end repeat
            repeat while lst ends with linefeed or lst ends with return
                set lst to text 1 thru -2 of lst
            end repeat
            set mnuBar to "___________________________________________/EDIT\\____"
            set chosn to (choose from list {mnuBar} & (paragraphs of lst) default items prev with multiple selections allowed)
            if class of chosn is boolean then
                set msg to "User canceled."
                say msg without waiting until completion
                return msg
            end if
            if chosn begins with mnuBar then
                if (count of chosn) > 1 then set chosn to items 2 thru -1 of chosn --keep selection
                set msg to "Edit menu items:"
                say msg without waiting until completion
                set lst to text returned of (display dialog msg default answer return & lst & return)
                set prev to chosn
            else
                set prev to chosn
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        repeat with chos in chosn
            say chos without waiting until completion
            display dialog contents of chos
        end repeat
    end repeat
end choosefromList
```

[2] This activates a dropdown menu from the top menu item.

```
return my choosefromList(lst)
property lst : ("
1
2
3
")
property prev : {}
property mnu2 : {}
property dropdown : false
on choosefromList(lst)
    repeat
        repeat
            ---------------------MENU 1---------------------
            set mnuBar to "                                                                                    Preferences ⚙️"
            set chosn to (choose from list {mnuBar} & mnu2 & (paragraphs 2 thru -2 of lst) default items prev with multiple selections allowed)
            if class of chosn is boolean then
                set msg to "User canceled."
                say msg without waiting until completion
                return msg
            end if
            if chosn begins with mnuBar then
                if (count of chosn) > 1 then set prev to items 2 thru -1 of chosn --keep selection
                ------------------DROPDOWN HANDLER---------------------     
                set dropdown to item (1 + (dropdown as integer)) of {true, false} --toggled
                if dropdown then
                    say "preferences on" without waiting until completion
                    set mnu2 to {"  A.", "  B.", "  C."}
                else
                    say "preferences off" without waiting until completion
                    set mnu2 to {}
                end if
                ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
            else
                set prev to chosn
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        ---------------------MAIN MENU HANDLER--------------------- 
        repeat with chos in chosn
            say chos without waiting until completion
            display dialog contents of chos
        end repeat
        -------------------------------------------------------------------
    end repeat
end choosefromList
```